# Construction of Lebesgue measure in Rudin's RCA book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

This theorem from Rudin's RCA book. Here's one moment from it's proof which seems to me very weird.

[image]

Rudin states that equality $\lambda(E)=m(E)$ holds for all Borel sets. But I think that it's even true for all $E\in \mathfrak{M}$.

Suppose $E\in \mathfrak{M}$ then $m(E)=\inf \{m(V): E\subset V, V \text{is open}\}=\inf \{\lambda(V): E\subset V, V \text{is open}\}$ since $\lambda(V)=m(V)$ because $V$ is open and the last $\inf$ is equal to $\lambda(E)$ since $\lambda$ is regular. So $m(E)=\lambda(E)$.

P.S. How does one prove that $\lambda(E)=m(E)$ holds for Borel sets $E$? How to show it rigorous? I have no ideas.

**EDIT:** Let $E\in \mathfrak{M}$ and since $\lambda$ and $m$ are regular. Then $$\lambda(E)=\inf \{\lambda(V): E\subset V, V ~\text{is open}\}$$ But we know that $\lambda(V)=m(V)$ for open set $V$. Hence $$\inf \{\lambda(V): E\subset V, V ~\text{is open}\}=\inf \{m(V): E\subset V, V ~\text{is open}\}$$
Since $m$ is regular then last inf is $m(E)$. What's wrong with this proof?

Comment: As I understand, $\lambda$ just not defined for arbitrary $E\in\mathfrak{M}$

Comment: @Glinka, Hmm that makes sense! But I can't prove that $\mu(E)=\lambda(E)$ for Borel set $E$. Can  you show please? Unfortunately i have no ideas :(

Comment: Could you send me a copy of the book?

Comment: @Glinka, Done! Take it

Comment: [Box topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology) coincides with [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the latter coincides with ordinary Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. So any open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ can be represented as a *countable disjoint* union of boxes. Thus $\lambda$ is defined for any open set $E$ and $\lambda(E)=m(E)$. To extend this for Borel sets we have to consider  the operations of countable intersection and relative complement as well.

Comment: @Glinka, you know Rudin didn't introduce such notions like product topology in his book and I totally didn't understand your proof. What do you think about my edit?